# How to skip editor prompt when squashing commits during git rebase -i?

Tags: git

Say I have a Git repository with a very long commit history. I want to run an interactive rebase to squash several commits together.

By default Git prompts the text editor for the user to edit the commit message after each squashing completes, but what I want is to skip the editor and use the merged commit message directly (since the rebase process could take many hours to complete, I don't want to bother waiting aside the computer to edit after each sqashing). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interactive rebase uses your preferred *sequence editor* to edit the commands to run, but your preferred *Git editor* to edit the squashed messages.  You can therefore set up the interactive rebase with two different editors: one that actually edits, and the other that just says *everything worked, we're all done*.  If you don't choose a sequence editor, the default is your preferred Git editor, so that you don't see any difference, but if you *do* choose two separate editors, you do.

From the command line, then, you would use:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=<your editor> GIT_EDITOR=true git rebase -i
```

As [phd pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50373808/how-to-skip-editor-prompt-when-squashing-commits-during-git-rebase-i/50374400?noredirect=1#comment87767863_50374400) we can have Git insert your own chosen editor (from, e.g., your `core.editor` setting) via shell expansion, such as this sh / bash syntax:

```
GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR=$(git var GIT_EDITOR) GIT_EDITOR=true git rebase -i
```

This will use the `/bin/true` program (or its shell built in equivalent) to "edit" each merged commit message.

Comment: Brilliant idea! Is there a quick way to use default git editor as the GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR?

Comment: Ask git to name the editor with `git var GIT_EDITOR`: `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="$(git var GIT_EDITOR)" GIT_EDITOR=true git rebase -i`.

Comment: @torek Is there a reason for removal of the `""` around the `$(...)`? AFAIK the double quotes can prevent a possible break due to space chars in the output of `$(...)`.

Comment: @DannyLin the result of command expansion during variable setting  like this doesn't get broken at spaces, as that particular phase of evaluation has already expired. *Using* the variable later, in the shell, *does* require the quotes, but we're just setting it into the environment, so the quotes are not required. They do no harm if you use them, though, and I used to always use them for consistency and/or paranoia. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax sugar on @torek's approach:

1. Set explicit `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` in your shell profile, .zshrc (or equivalent):

```
open ~/.zshrc
```

Paste:

```bash
export EDITOR="code --wait"
export GIT_EDITOR="code --wait -n"
export GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="code --wait -n"
```

2. Run `GIT_EDITOR=true git rebase -i`

Comment: FYI `$GIT_EDITOR` and/or `$GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` seem to "break" the github desktop app. You can drag/drop commits, but it'll just open your `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR` and, not actually work